# Service Worker generated by polymer does not work when i override the host in polymer serve or if i use HTTPS protocol

Tags: polymer, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, lit-element

I am new to `polymer` and I am trying to build a `PWA` application. I followed their starter kit which can be viewed [here](https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/setup). But I cant make the generated `service-worker.js` work when i pass `-P https` or `-H 192.168.10.98` on polymer serve command. Although not passing the parameters makes the service-worker work without any errors.

This is how I follow the instruction in the way I understood them,

1. First I do polymer build
2. Then I copy the folder inside the build file with the es* bundle that i want.
3. Inside the copied folder I do `polymer serve`.

If I execute polymer serve alone, everything in service worker works fine,

But when i do `polymer serve -P https` or `polymer serve -H 192.168.10.98`
the app gets loaded but without the `PWA` service worker functionality which is resiliency in offline situation.

I am stuck with this problem for days and I will really appreciate any help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

This happens because service worker does not work with self-signed certificates by default.

Because of this, the service-worker.js loaded by Polymer is not loaded properly.

To make it work using self signed certificate, i need to launch chrome with this command as we need to pass extra parameters.

'chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Temp --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https:/localhost:8081/'